# data table:: fread how to parse string "[4, 5, 66, -99]" into numeric vector for each row?

Tags: r, data.table, fread, file-format

I create a data table via an `fread` from a `csv` file that includes rows like: `[4, 5, 77, 22, 44]`. R reads this in as a string like so:

```
> user_data[5, sport]
[1] "[18, 18]"
```

Each row's array can have any length from 0 to very long - that is each row is different (non-rectangular data). How can I turn this into an array? I've tackled this problem with dataframes via the following:

```
for(name in array_columns){
  user_data[[name]] = strsplit(gsub("^\\[|\\]$","",as.character(user_data[[name]])),", |\\[|\\]")
  user_data[[name]][[1]]= as.numeric(user_data[[name]][[1]]) 
}
```

However, if I run the same code on a data table (which I don't want to do anyway since I want to update by reference rather than copying) I only achieve parsing the string into a character array:

```
> user_data[5, sport]
[[1]]
[1] "18" "18"
```

It seems like the second line of the loop is ineffective. I also tried:

```
name = "sport"
> user_data[ , eval(parse(text = paste0(name, ":=as.numeric(", name, ")" )))]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

And finally:

```
> user_data[ , eval(parse(text = paste0(name, ":=as.numeric(", name, "[[1]])" )))]
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(user_data, , eval(parse(text = paste0(name, ":=as.numeric(",  :
  Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 69973 items of column 'sport' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
2: In `[.data.table`(user_data, , eval(parse(text = paste0(name, ":=as.numeric(",  :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'list' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 69973 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'list' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
> user_data[5, sport][[1]]
[1] 24 <---!!!!Wrong value, should be [18, 18]
```

I need to access these vectors numerically so I can generate summary statistics for each row depending on the value of these vectors. How can I do it and why is my above code not working? Thanks for any advice.

Here's a few rows of the data table:

```
> head(full[ , .(sport, duration.y)], 10)
                       sport                                         duration.y
 1:                   [-999]                                             [6.37]
 2:               [94, -999]                                       [15.65, 4.5]
 3:             [-999, -999]                                     [28.0, 3600.0]
 4:             [-999, -999]                                     [28.0, 3600.0]
 5:                   [-999]                                             [15.0]
 6:                   [-999]                                              [1.0]
 7:                   [-999]                                             [17.0]
 8: [3, 3, -999, 3, 3, -999] [10191.84, 1321.17, 4.89, 10191.84, 1321.17, 4.89]
 9:                   [-999]                                             [30.0]
10:             [-999, -999]                                        [2.0, 16.0]
```

Per row the length of each array in each column will be the same, but it's different between rows. Also not all columns come in array form, some are simple character or numeric values.

Comment: Post us a snippet of the file, say 10 lines. More specifically, **a) Do all rows have the same number of columns and b) Can the lists [...] be nested?** Why would `user_data[5, sport]` be `[18, 18]` since that has 2 elements, when you showed us `[4, 5, 77, 22, 44]` with 5 elements?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit on the Baroque side of programming but this function will take a vector of character values like those and apply a function to each row separately:

```
scan.sub <- function(x, func=mean, sep=',', remove="[][]"){
  sapply( 
    sapply(x, function(x) as.numeric( scan(text=gsub(patt=remove, rep="", x), sep=sep)) ),
      # this section reads the text after stripping the brackets and making numeric
    func)}  # the outer `sapply` applies the function, `func` to each row of numerics
```

After adding quiet=TRUE to the scan arguments I get this from a data.table similar to yours:

```
> full[ , lapply(.SD, scan.sub)]
     sport duration.y
 1: -999.0      6.370
 2: -452.5     10.075
 3: -999.0   1814.000
 4: -999.0   1814.000
 5: -999.0     15.000
 6: -999.0      1.000
 7: -999.0     17.000
 8: -331.0   3839.300
 9: -999.0     30.000
10: -999.0      9.000
```